# How do I write query if I want 1st day of the month falls in 1st week in T-SQL

Tags: sql

How do I write query if I want 1st day of the month falls in 1st week. my report needs to show data from SUN-SAT.so,
if I run the report on anyway current week, it should only show the data for the previous week from SUN-Sat.
Even though 10/27 falls in the 5th week of October , I am required to show as 10/27- 11/02 falls in the first week of November since November 1 falls in the first 
week of November.

Here it is how I want to display the  date-range in my report for the month of November. and the same logic applies
for every month.

Week 1  10/27 to 11/02

Week 2  11/03 to 11/09

Week 3  11/10 to 11/16

Week 4  11/17 to 11/23

Week 5  11/24 to 11/30

so, I am not counting till 4th week of October not the 5th one because I am counting 5th week as week 1 for
November.

like wise, the first week of JAN will be 12/29 till 01/04 . I don't want to count  5th week of December because if
I count, there will be duplication.

Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: SQL Server or Sybase? please add an appropriate tag

Comment: and is a simpler way to put things that any week that ends in the following month should be included in that later month rather than the month that it starts in?

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, an entire week 'belongs' to a specific month based on whatever month the Saturday of that week lies in.  Then you want to work backwards and calculate for a given month, the set of all weeks that belong to that month.

This will give you the forward calculation:

```
declare @date date = getdate();
select month(dateadd(day,7+datediff(day,@date,'2000-01-01')%7,@date))
```

And the reverse calculation:

```
declare @year int = 2013
declare @month int = 11
select
  datefromparts(@year,@month,1) as month,
  dateadd(day,i*7+datediff(day,datefromparts(@year,@month,1),'2000-01-01')%7-6,datefromparts(@year,@month,1)) week_start,
  dateadd(day,i*7+datediff(day,datefromparts(@year,@month,1),'2000-01-01')%7  ,datefromparts(@year,@month,1)) week_end
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) wk(i)
```

- I use datediff(day,@date,@known_date) instead of datepart(dw,@date) because it is deterministic.